# How to change the id attribute of the HTML element in .net

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

I'm entirely new to .net, and am working in C# Visual Studio 2010. The ID attribute of the  element is getting auto-generated, and I need it to be id="ng-app".

Can someone explain how I can go about doing this? But please keep the explanation as 'noob-friendly' as possible.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ClentIDMode` and use the value `Static`.

Usually you will need to use this when your controls are inside a master page. But be cautios on using the `Static` you might end up with controls with same id in client side

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/system.web.ui.clientidmode.aspx

Here is an example for you

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" 
              ClientIDMode="Static" 
              DataSourceID="XmlDataSource1" runat="server" />
```